# Ubuntu 18.04 detects wired connection and has access to LAN connections, but can't reach the internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet

First off, I'm very new with Ubuntu, this is a work computer I'm trying to setup. Any help will be greatly appreciated! It's a prebuilt that doesn't have a wifi card, but two ethernet ports (dual xeon machine for scientific computing purposes).

When I plug my ethernet cable in, which works for other windows machines, the 1000MB/s connection is detected in the settings, if I try and ping any local IP adress, it works flawlessly, but I can't have any access whatsoever to the internet, whatever IP I try, I'll get a message that the host was unavailable.

Edit : If it can help, here's the output when I run ifconfig :

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4639:c4ff:fe92:94f7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 44:39:c4:92:94:f7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 733  bytes 101263 (101.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 150  bytes 31120 (31.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xd3e00000-d3e7ffff

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 44:39:c4:92:94:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd3f00000-d3f20000

eth1:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.11.150  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 44:39:c4:92:94:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd3f00000-d3f20000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1022  bytes 63852 (63.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1022  bytes 63852 (63.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've tried pretty much every combination of disabling IPv6, manually setting up the connectiong, etc., to no avail. In general when it wouldn't work I'd run `sudo ifdown -a` and then `sudo ifup -a`, but it hasn't worked this time...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Have a good day! :)

Comment: If the cable works for Windows then the network probably uses DHCP. In that case you shouldn't configure anything manually but set up the connection for automatic configuration (ie. DHCP) on Ubuntu too. Nor do I see that disabling IPv6 could possibly help. It normally does more harm than good nowadays.

Comment: If this work computer is in a business/corporate environment, contact your IT Dept, as they may be filtering MAC addresses to increase security.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a routing issue - you can review your routes with `ip route`. If the first line doesn't start with `default via <ipaddress>` then that's probably it. You can add a default route with `sudo ip route add default via <ipaddress>`

There should only be one default route.

Also remember that the most specific route is traversed first. For example, if you want to get to 10.1.1.20, this will be sent on the adaptor with 10.1.1.0/25, not the adaptor with 10.1.1.0/24. Also have a look at the adaptor Metric, with the lower the metric having a higher priority.

It's possible that you might have some firewall rules blocking your traffic if there is some assymetric routing happening i.e. traffic going out one adaptor and returning on another.

You can also disable ipv6 until reboot with 
`sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

If you think it might be a DNS issue, you can check your settings with 
`systemd-resolve --status` and
`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried ip route and the first line wasn't my router's IP, the second line was! So I used your function to add a default via my routeur's local IP, which now shows up as the first line, but it didn't manage to fix the issue, and IPv6 is already disabled! Any other ideas? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Sounds like you have more than one default route... Make sure there's only one line that says default.

Answer (score 0):

To everyone getting on this thread, I fixed it! I thought it was weird that there were the eth0 and eth1 ports but not a second paragraph for eth0, and found out I had to add eth0 to my etc/network/interfaces file! Thank you for trying to help, it's very much appreciated! :)